# Struts 1 Tomcat not working in windows 7

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, struts1

I installed Tomcat 6.0.35 Server. My struts application not working in windows 7. I am getting the error when running my struts application:

```
exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.
    org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.getModuleConfig(TagUtils.java:755)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.computeURLWithCharEncoding(TagUtils.java:364)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.computeURLWithCharEncoding(TagUtils.java:285)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.RedirectTag.generateRedirectURL(RedirectTag.java:289)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.RedirectTag.doEndTag(RedirectTag.java:268)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_logic_005fredirect_005f0(index_jsp.java:87)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:60)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: i added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of multiple reasons. 
Check [struts module null not found](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ModuleNull)

Also, make sure that you have not mixed up `.jars`

Comment: You should mark the question as answered. It encourages the people to answer your questions.